# kendo dropdown and bootstrap dropdown on the same page

Tags: css, kendo-dropdown

I have to use Kendo "dropdown" css class and Bootstrap "dropdown" css class on the same page. Is there any way that i can achieve this?

Is there a way to use something like an alias for either of these so that there is no conflict?

RIght now, what happens is, the Kendo "dropdown" css class has higher priority and it overrides the bootstrap "dropdown" class. I want the kendo drop down for a dropdown box and the bootstrap dropdown class for a dropdown menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you simply need to modify the source css file (which means you can not use CDN anymore if you did).

Just go to the bootsrap (or kendo) css file which you are including, search for ".dropdown" and change the class name to something else.